# Generate a tree node (no binary) with recursive from a matrix (of arrays) in python

Tags: python

I know that thee recursive built a binary tree node, so there must be a change to get it with the variable matrix that generate a array of arrays.

```
matrix = [np.random.randint(1,2*N,N) for i in range(N)]

class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None, up=None, down=None): 
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.up = up
        self.down = down
    def albe(self, tipo=True, nivel =level, a=-100,b=100):
        if nivel ==0:
            return(self,0)
        if self.up is None:
            if self.right is None:
                if self.left is None:
                    if self.down is None:
                        return (self,0)
                    return self.down.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a,b)
        if self.down is None:
            if self.left is None:
                if self.right is None:
                    return self.up.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a,b)
        if self.left is None:
            return self.right.akbe(not tipo. nivel-1, a,b)
        if self.right is None:
            return self.left.albe(not tipo, nivel-1,a,b)
        l,_ = self.left.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a, b)
        u,_ = self.up.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a, b)
        d,_ = self.down.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a binary tree
class Node:
#function

```
def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.up = None
    self.down = None


def albe(self, tipo=True, nivel =level, a=-100,b=100):
    if nivel ==0:
        return(self,0)
    if self.left is None:
        if self.right is None:
            return (self,0)
        return self.right.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a,b)
    if self.right is None:
        return self.left.albe(not tipo, nivel-1,a,b)
    l,_ = self.left.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a, b)
    if tipo:
        if l.data>a:
            a = l.dato
        if a>=b:
            return(Node(b),-1)
        r,_=self.right.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a,b)
        if l.data<r.data:
            return(r,1)
        return(l,-1)
    if l.data<b:
        b = l.data
        if a>=b:
            return(Node(a),-1)
    r,_=self.right.albe(not tipo, nivel-1, a, b)
    if l.data>r.data:
        return(r,1)
    return(l,-1)
```